# Animate flickers last sequence of opacity animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, opacity

I have three div elements that I animate from `opacity: 0` > `opacity: 1`.

I animate the last two elements at the same time and for some reason **I experience some weird flickering when the last element hits `opacity: 1`**

http://jsfiddle.net/dmfux4LL/ (notice the "IMAGE 2" text to the outer right)

The flickering has been noted in Firefox + Chrome.

*Bonus question*: For some reason the "image 2" text doesnt even animate in IE.

What im doing is:

```
CSS:
#frame1-image1, #frame1-image2, #logo-container {
    opacity: 0;
}
JS:
frame1Image1.delay(300).animate(
    { opacity: 1 },
    {
        duration: defaultDurationTime, 
        easing: 'swing',
        complete: function() { // the callback
            console.log("done");
        }
    });

frame1Image2.delay(400).animate(
    { opacity: 1 },
    {
        duration: defaultDurationTime, 
        easing: 'swing',
        complete: function() { // the callback
            console.log("done");
        }
    });

logoContainer.delay(400).animate(
    { opacity: 1 },
    {
        duration: defaultDurationTime, 
        easing: 'swing',
        complete: function() { // the callback
            console.log("done");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think it's because of your images' colours combined with the animation timing. The flickering you see is one layer getting close to opacity 1 while the other is trying to do the same so you see what you see now. http://jsfiddle.net/dmfux4LL/1/ is how it looks without the css, as you can see everything fades in correctly. The image in `frame1-image2` is the one making this happen

Comment: If the animation is simply the opacity going from 0 to 1 you can use CSS transitions triggered by javascript which will give you simpler code and probably performance improvements.

Comment: It's also because the stacking order has the right side under the middle, for example http://jsfiddle.net/dmfux4LL/2/ it works because I set the z-index to be higher.

Comment: Huangism > z-index to the rescue. Do make a post and ill accept it. Thanks everyone for chipping in!